# A template constructor that never can be called GCC

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, compiler-errors, g++

In the following snippet GCC decides to call the default constructor instead of the copy constructor. The constructor has a template argument, which is not used, therefore the template argument type can not be deduced. Yes the compiler generates a default copy constructor and calls it but it seems like a better behavior by the compiler would issue an error. Can some one explain the reasoning behind this?

Also if there is a template argument on a method, and that template argument is not used in the method. And that template argument is not of the class which the method is inside, shouldn't the compiler give at least a warning?

```
#include <iostream> 

using namespace std;


template< typename T >
class Test
{};

template< typename T >
class Test1
{
public:

    Test1() : m_t() { std::cout << "Default constructor" << std::endl; }

    template< typename A >
    Test1( const Test1< T >& other ) : m_t( other.m_t ) { std::cout << "Copy constructor" << std::endl; }

    template< typename A >
    Test1( Test1< T >&& other ) : m_t( std::move( other.m_t ) ) { std::cout << "Move constructor" << std::endl; }

    void omg() { std::cout << &m_t << std::endl; }

private:

    T m_t;

};  //  class Test



int main()  
{

    try
    {
        Test1< Test< int > > mm;

        Test1< Test< int > > mm1( mm );

        mm1.omg();

    }
    catch ( const exception& stdException )
    {
        cout << stdException.what() << endl;
    }

    return ( 0 );
}
```

The result of running the above code are:

```
Default constructor
0x7ffcac82708f
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The text `Default constructor` comes from the line: `Test1< Test< int > > mm;`. It's not "instead of" anything.

The line `Test1< Test< int > > mm1( mm );` calls the copy-constructor, which is implicitly defined since you did not define one or do anything to suppress generation of such.  The implicitly defined copy constructor produces no output. This is well-defined behaviour, not "random" in any sense.

`template< typename A > Test1( const Test1< T >& other )` is not a copy-constructor. [Copy constructors cannot be templates.](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor)

gcc doesn't appear to have the option of warning about unused template parameters. In [this Bugzilla thread](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=43386) someone requested it and a developer responded that sometimes it is intentional to not use template parameters , e.g. in the case of a specialization that only needs some of them.

Comment: All that you said is correct. But I defined a method, which can never be called. And that is not the right way to go by my opinion

Comment: @rrrrTTTrrrr Maybe you could file a feature request to gcc to warn about uncallable template constructor